# Using WhiteboxTools in QGIS 3.10/3.12

Tags: qgis, installation, whitebox-tools

i`m working with QGIS 3.10 and 3.12, trying to use the WhiteboxTools plugin. I followed the WBT-Manual (point 3.4 QGIS Plugin).The Repository details dialog box is mentioned as "https://plugins.bruy.me/plugins/plugins.xml" but it creates the Error: 
**"Error transferring https://plugins.bruy.me/plugins/plugins.xml?qgis=3.12 - server replied: Not Found"**
Is there a new link needed? 
My friend got the same problem. Worked 1 month ago, but now he has the same error.
I'm using Windows 10.

Comment: I have been getting the error for a while now every time I look at the plugins in my QGIS (I added Bruy's repository in the settings some time ago) but haven't found any explanation.  To get the plugin you might try GitHub: https://github.com/alexbruy/processing-whitebox

Comment: The author deleted a related issue in his github repo: https://github.com/alexbruy/processing-whitebox/issues/28 so I guess he withdrew the plugin.

Answer (score 1):

They updated the repo link.

 The following repo link should be used (https://plugins.bruy.me/plugins/plugins.xml). This fix is also mentioned [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/358465/96381)

 Note that QGIS 3.8 or higher is required to successfully load the plugin.