# Installing Whitebox in QGIS without broken repo link

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, installation, whitebox-tools

I need to install Whitebox tools in QGIS. I have tried to follow the instructions provided in [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/331321/96381) but the repo link is broken (https://plugins.bruy.me/plugins/plugins.xml and https://plugins.bruy.me/processing-whitebox.html). The same problem is also mentioned here in this [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/354223/96381)

I have tried to `install the plugin from zip` but it did not work. The zip file was download from [Github repo](https://github.com/alexbruy/processing-whitebox).

Is there a working link to the repo or another method of adding the plugin offline in QGIS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Whitebox tools repo has been updated. 

The following repo link should be used (https://plugins.bruy.me/plugins/plugins.xml)

Then, follow the instructions on this website (https://jblindsay.github.io/wbt_book/qgis_plugin.html)
Note that QGIS 3.8 or higher is required to successfully load the plugin

Comment: I am pointing out @Polygeo that the plugin seems to have an error whereby the answers here maybe incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

There is an error with the plugin that means it will install/function in QGIS 3.16.2 but not in QGIS 3.10.13